# the 1st click of button validates data in a CKeditor, for the second click it does not take the modified data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am validating data present in CKeditor on a button click event using jquery. After the button click it separates the list of correct answers and wrong answers. This works fine. But after modifying the wrong answers and hit the button, it again takes the initially entered values. How to make it take the modified data on the 2nd button click.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="../ckeditor/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

     CKEDITOR.replace('Field');

     var correctZips = new Array;
         var wrongZips = new Array;
     var CorZip;
     var WorZip;

     $('#save').click(function () {

        var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances['Field'].getData();
        var element = $(editor_data).text().split(",");

            $.each((element), function (index, value) {
            if(this.length=5 && jQuery.isNumeric(this)) {
                    correctZips= correctZips+"<span>"+this+"</span>"+",";


                }else {
                    wrongZips= wrongZips+"<span id='flip' style=\"background-color: yellow; \">"+this+"</span>"+",";
                }
            }
            )   


            CKEDITOR.instances.Field.setData((correctZips + wrongZips), function (index, value){

            })
        //$("#save").attr("disabled", "disabled");       
     });         
 });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="Field"></textarea>
<button id ="save">Verify the ZipCodes</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Regards,
Steven

Comment: You should post your code as my crystal ball is broken

Answer (score 0):

You are deinfing the 2 `ZIPS` variables as arrays outside of the click handler. You need to reset them for each time a click occurs so they need to be defined inside the handler and they shouldn't be defined as arrays since you are using them to concatenate strings

```
 $('#save').click(function () {
      var correctZips = '', wrongZips='';/* start with empty strings*/
      /* remainder of your handler code*/
 });
```